# How to make a non clickable menu Item in UIMenu?

Tags: ios, swift, uimenu

How to make a non clickable menu Item in UIContextMenuConfiguration?
At the moment, when I click on the menu item, nothing happens and the menu just closes.
I need the menu not to close when I click on the item.

Here is some code:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
var contextMenuConfiguration: UIContextMenuConfiguration {
    let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(
        identifier: nil,
        previewProvider: nil
    ) { [weak self] _ -> UIMenu? in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return nil }

        var actions: [UIAction] = []
        actions.append(
            UIAction(title: "\(l10n(.id)) \(strongSelf.connection.id)",
                     image: UIImage(systemName: "info.circle")) { _ in
            strongSelf.delegate?.idPressed()
        })
```

And here code of my func:

```
func idPressed() {
    <#code#>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this problem with next solution:

```
    actions.append(
        UIAction(
            title: "\(l10n(.id)) \(strongSelf.connection.id)",
            image: UIImage(systemName: "info.circle"),
            attributes: .disabled) { _ in
            return
        }
    )
```